# How can you have a page with a button that change views that is not a table view? (iPhone Developing)

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I asked a similar question and someone gave me a tutorial link. But, the link made me use a table view and it looks bad with all the lines and stuff. So how do I just make a view with a button and background and stuff (Please write steps in 1.2.3.. format and it would be nice if you attached the code needed too.)???

Comment: Please leave the question correctly tagged. The tags are not there to simply be a repeat of the subject line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to fit that kind of project into a comment field, and, in any case, the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty.

Take a look at the *Utility* sample project that is built into Xcode. Create a new project in Xcode, and under the iPhone Application templates, select *Utility Application*. This template project uses a button to switch between two views.

Comment: I tested it and it worked well. But the flipside view thing is already implemented in my app. How can I add a homepage like thing in the beginning then when you click a button it goes to the view with the content?? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the navigation controller template. The navigation controller lets you manage a hierarchy of view controllers.

Comment: But the ones I have seen all use tables views and cells.

Comment: A navigation controller just pushes and pops any view controller you give it. Xcode's template app uses table views, but there's nothing requiring that *you* use table views. You can use any view you like in each view controller.

Comment: Oh. Ok I got it now. Thanks I did a little exploring and I learned some stuff. Thanks agian.